# If $a_{n+1}=a_n(1-a_n)$ is given, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(na_n)=1$ if $a_1 \in(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

Now, I have proven that sequence $a_n$ is monotonically decreasing and that its range is $a_n \in (0,1)$, so that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$, but I'm really struggling to prove the other part of the question.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ if $a_1 \in (0,1)$, right?

Comment: Hint: show that $\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: @Lucas Yes because if a limit L exists it must satisfy $L=L-L^2\Leftrightarrow 0=L^2\Leftrightarrow L=0$

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$na_n =\frac{n}{\frac1{a_n}}\to 1$$

indeed by Stolz-Cesaro

$$\frac{n+1-n}{\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}}=\frac{1}{\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}} \to 1$$

with

$$\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}=\frac{a_{n}-a_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}a_{n}}=\frac{a_n^2}{a_n^2(1-a_n)}=\frac1{1-a_n} \to 1$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I foolishly forgot about Stolz's theorem.

Comment: @zare023 You are welcome! Bye